# Adding Content Type field when adding new KeyVault secret via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

So I am trying to use powershell to add new secrets into the Keyvault I am using the line below :

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name "NAMEOFVAULT" --name "KEYNAME" --value "KEYVALUE"
```

I am now trying to add the content type (--content-type) using Powershell as well but failing everytime.

Dones anyone have a solution out there ?

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name "NAMEOFVAULT" --name "KEYNAME" --value "KEYVALUE" --content-type "TEST"
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Sep 27, 2022, you can use the `--description` field to set the content type, i.e.

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name "NAMEOFVAULT" --name "KEYNAME" --value "KEYVALUE" --description "password"
```

A [pull request has just been merged](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/23988) that adds a `--content-type` option as well.
I assume this will be available in azure cli versions after 2.40.0

Comment: 1 year later --content-type still does not work (for me at least). --description does the trick, though. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You must set the content type after setting the secret itself. Use `az keyvault secret set-attribute` command.

```sh
$ KV_NAME="NAMEOFVAULT"
$ SECRET_KEY_NAME="KEYNAME"
$ az keyvault secret set-attributes \
  --content-type "my-content-type" \
  --id "https://${KV_NAME}.vault.azure.net/secrets/${SECRET_KEY_NAME}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az_keyvault_secret_set_attributes